# preloading images in a css3 background slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow, preload, preloading

I am working on a CSS3 landing page for a client of mine that uses background images. I am having trouble getting images to preload.

I saw this method but am unsure how to apply it to this scenario: http://perishablepress.com/preload-images-css3/

**Website:** http://museiam.ca/splash/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> 
<html class="ie ie6 no-js" lang="en">
   <![endif]-->
   <!--[if IE 7 ]>    
   <html class="ie ie7 no-js" lang="en">
      <![endif]-->
      <!--[if IE 8 ]>    
      <html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en">
         <![endif]-->
         <!--[if IE 9 ]>    
         <html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en">
            <![endif]-->
            <!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
            <html class="no-js" lang="en">
               <!--<![endif]-->
               <head>
                  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
                  <title>MUSEIAM.ca</title>
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                  <meta name="description" content="MUSEIAM.ca" />
                  <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2" />
                  <meta name="author" content="MUSEIAM.ca" />
                  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
               </head>
               <body id="page">

                  <div id class="cb-slideshow">
                     <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
                     <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
                     <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
                     <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
                     <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
                     <li><span>Image 06</span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <IMG class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="...">
                  <a href="#"><IMG class="enter" src="images/enter.png" alt="..." onmouseover="this.src='images/enter2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/enter.png'" ></a><a href="#"><IMG class="enter2" src="images/entrer.png" alt="..." onmouseover="this.src='images/entrer2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/entrer.png'" ></a>
                  <div id="footer">&copy; 2014 MUSEIAM.CA. All Rights Reserved.</div>
               </body>
            </html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.svg#BebasNeueRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
/* CSS reset */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
input{
    border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
    padding:3px 5px 4px;
    color:#979797;
    width:190px;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;
}
/* General Demo Style */
body{
    font-family: Constantia, Palatino, "Palatino Linotype", "Palatino LT STD", Georgia, serif;
    background: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #aa3e03;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.ie7 body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
a{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
t-align: center;
}
.clr{
    clear: both;
}
img.logo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
img.enter{
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -105px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
}
img.enter2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 105px;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    }
#footer {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 5px; 
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container > header{
        text-align: center;
    }
}lor: #fff;
}
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 { 
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg) 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(../images/6.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}
/* Animation for the slideshow images */
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Animation for the title */
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for preloading.

```
var imageArray = new Array();

window.onload = function(){
    for(i = 0; i <= maxIndex; ++i)
    {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = "images/myImage" + Number(i + 1) + ".jpg";
        imageArray[i] = image;
    }
}
```

Name all the images like this: myImage1.jpg, myImage2.jpg   ect.
Then just iterate through this array to change the image. maxIndex is how many pictures you have.